# View not updating on $scope.foo change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

There are a couple of similar questions to the following one on SO. The ones I found have answers that are either out of date, wrong or do not solve my problem.

The following snippets are stripped down to what seems essential for this question.

View:

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <!-- some stuff -->
    <ng-include src="getPartial(case.status)"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Relevant parts of the included partial:

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox" for="iterationDiarySurvey">
        <a ng-show="surveyDiaryMailSent == 0" ng-click="sendMail('diaryLinks')">
            Send Mail
        </a>
        <span ng-show="surveyDiaryMailSent == 1" class="badge">Mail sent</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

`sendMail()` function that is called on click:

```
$scope.sendMail = function(type) {
    <!-- snip -->
    } else if (type == 'diaryLinks') {
        Mail.create({some data}).then(function() {
            $scope.surveyDiaryMailSent = 1;
        });
    }
};
```

The **expected behaviour** when the promise is fulfilled with success would be that since `$scope.surveyDiaryMailSent` is set to 1, the `<a>` element disappears and the `<span>` element shows.

This doesn't happen though. Only after a manual refresh of the browser.

I do the same (very similar) thing in other places and it always works fine. I just can't get the view updated in this particular case.

---

What doesn't help:

- wrapping the assignment or the service call in `$apply`. Results in the usual error that says something along the lines of 'digest already ongoing'.
- adding `$apply` after the assignment, same reasons

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.apply()` after setting `surveyDiaryMailSent`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it with $scope.$apply? I mean something like: $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.surveyDiaryMailSent = 1; });

Comment: Yes, of course I have tried that. But it's neither necessary nor helpful. It results in the expected error that a digest is already going on.

Comment: In your example, the span tag is not closed. If that's the case in the real code, it might be the reason for the problem.

Comment: Nope, that was just a mistake from trimming the stuff down.

Comment: Have your tried `!surveyDiaryMailSent` vs `surveyDiaryMailSent` in your `ng-show`?

Comment: That really shouldn't make a difference but I'm going to try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown the code for the `Mail` class so I can't be certain if the promise returned by `Mail.send()` is an Angular promise or not. However, you can wrap the call with `$q.when()` to help make sure Angular is aware when the promise is resolved:

```
function MyController($scope, Mail, $q) {
    /* ... */
    $scope.sendMail = function(type) {
        /* ... */
        $q.when(Mail.create({some data})).then(function(result) {
            // result will be the resolved value
            $scope.surveyDiaryMailSent = 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. I assumed all along that angular is aware of the promises returned by the $http service. This solved my problem, thanks a lot!